# Enigma: How can my iPad mini without GPS know his location?

Tags: ios, ipad, geolocation

I have an iPad mini, non-cellular, without GPS.

Yesterday, I had opened the app RATP. In the app, I had a map. I took my iPad outside, in Paris. I opened my iPad. I still had the map. **And — surprise, surprise! — the iPad showed my location on the map. When I moved, the iPad showed my new location!**

**How is this wonder possible?**

Comment: Was WiFi active at this time?

Comment: AFAIK iOS deduces the location from the various WiFi hotspots around you if possible.

Comment: @patrix — I had left wi-fi on. But I had no wi-fi connection, I was about 15 km away from my home.

Comment: @patrix - How? The iPad can know which wi-fi networks are nearby. But then what?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=location+based+on+wifi+signals&t=ipad&ia=web

Comment: @patrix - Location based on wi-fi signals uses a database of access points or wi-fi networks, as far as I know. To access this database, a device needs Internet connection, no?